# Array to string conversion cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I'm working on Cake PHP. Please give me a solution  to solve this:

**Controller.php:**

```
public function test() {
    $this->set('users_list', $this->User->find('list', array('fields' => array('User.id', 'User.fullname'))));
}
```

**test.ctp:**

```
<?php echo $users_list ?>
```

**Error:**

> Throws error : Array to string conversion php

I need to display the values.

Comment: Show the code where you use `users_list`. i.e your view file code exactly where error resides.

Comment: Presumably you want to do something like `<?php foreach($users_list as $user){ echo $user->fullname . "<br/>"; }`. I'm not saying that that's going to work 100% as written, but it should get you going in the right direction at least.

Comment: Might be a good idea to learn the basics of the php language before trying to use a framework?

Comment: thanks all for the quick response

Comment: code : <?php print_r($users_list);  ?> RESULT: <?php print_r($users_list);  ?> but i'm need to echo the result  "<?php echo $users_list;  ?>"  this code throws error "Notice (8): Array to string conversion [APP\View\Users\test.ctp, line 2]Array"

Comment: ` $this->User->find('list'` return Array, and you try just `echo` which intended to display string, so, `echo` throw such error. You should use `for` or `foreach` to iterate items in `$users_list` and echo values

Comment: @user2057530 Let's start with this… Do you know the difference between a [string](http://us2.php.net/language.types.string.php) and an [array](http://us2.php.net/language.types.array.php)?

Comment: what do you want to do with that string then? do you want to use it for js?

Comment: If you just want to test the values, use `debug()`

Answer (score 0):

test.ctp:

```
<?php echo "<pre>";print_r($users_list);echo "</pre>";  ?>
```

as the result of find will be an array so the above line will print all the elements of $user_list array, now you have to use this array according to your logic, for example you can use foreach() to get individual elements of this array.

Hope the above explanation is enough for your understanding!

Answer (score 0):

Your function should look like this:

```
public function test() {
    $this->set('users_list', $this->User->find('all', array('fields' => array('User.id',         'User.fullname'))));
}
```

Then in your view you should do a foreach loop to output the values like this:

```
foreach($users_list as $ul){
    echo 'This is the id: '.$ul[0]['User']['id'];
    echo ' This is the full name: '.$ul[0]['User']['fullname'];
}
```

that would be the way i'd do it but i don't know if its the best one

if you want something easier you can print an array with:

```
print_r($users_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String class. It has a very cool method called toList(), and it's used to print an array with an 'and' before the last element.

```
App::uses('String', 'Utility');
echo String::toList($users_list);
```

Check out the documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/string.html

Answer (score 0):

this Worked For me. Hope it will also work for you
Here is my ctp file code

```
 $this->Form->input('answertype',array('div'=>false,'label'=>false,'type'=>'select','multiple'> => 'checkbox', 'options' =>  $arrayOptions, 'class' => 'form-control  dropdown-menu-item '));
```

When i Debug in controller i got Result like This

```
array(
'PackageDescription' => array(
    'name' => 'Special Di scout Package',
    'question' => '20',
    'revision' => '32',
    'experttype' => '100',
    'responsetime' => '6',
    'answertype' => array(
        (int) 0 => 'image',
        (int) 1 => 'audio'
    ),
    'support' => 'email&sms',
    'status' => 'public'
)
```

)

and i make Some Changes in My Model to Store Any Array as String

```
 public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if(!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['answertype']) && $this->data[$this->alias]['answertype'] != ''){
            $subArr = $this->data[$this->alias]['answertype'];
            $this->data[$this->alias]['answertype'] = implode(',', $this->data[$this->alias]['answertype']);
            $my_model = ClassRegistry::init('Answer');
            $AnswerInfo = $my_model->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Answer.name' => $subArr), 'fields' => array('Answer.name', 'Answer.name')));
            if(!empty($AnswerInfo)){
                $answertype = array();
                foreach($AnswerInfo as $info){
                    $answertype[] = $info['Answer']['name'];
                }
                $this->data[$this->alias]['answertype'] = implode(',', $answertype);
            }
        }   
        if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['name']) && empty($this->data[$this->alias]['slug'])) {
            if(!isset($this->data[$this->alias]['id'])){
                $this->data[$this->alias]['slug']=$this->stringToSlug($this->data[$this->alias]['name']);
            }else{
                $this->data[$this->alias]['slug']=$this->stringToSlug($this->data[$this->alias]['name'],$this->data[$this->alias]['id']);
            }    
        }
        return true;
    }
```