# CakePHP array to string conversion error when uploading a video through a form to a live server

Tags: php, cakephp

We are trying to upload videos to our site through a form using CakePHP. On a local MAMP server everything works perfectly but on our live server (shared cloud hosting) we get the following error after the form posts:

> Notice (8): Array to string conversion
>   [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php, line 1009]
>
> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array'
>   in 'field list'

Instead of inserting the name of the file into the database it tries to insert an array, but only on our live server using the exact same code as out local dev server.

Here is the code for handling retrieval of the filename on post:

```
        $uploading = false;

        if (empty($this->request->data['Video']['filepath']['name'])) {
            unset($this->request->data['Video']['filepath']);
        }
        else
        {
            $tempFileName = $this->request->data['Video']['filepath']['tmp_name'];

            if (is_uploaded_file($tempFileName))
            {
                $uploading = true;
                $filename = $this->request->data['Video']['filepath']['name'];

                $this->request->data['Video']['filepath'] = $filename;
            }
        }
```

Any help with this issue would be great, cheers.

**EDIT:**
The code used to insert the data into the database, using the CakePHP save method.

```
if ($this->Video->save($this->request->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Video added!'));

    return $this->redirect(array('controller'=> 'games', 'action' => 'gameDetails', $slug));
}
```

Comment: This code does not provide enough context to see the problem. The error is thrown by the DboSource, meaning it's a result of a database operation (find/save). There is no database operation in your code sample.

Comment: have you tried anything so far to debug the problem? If so, let the people know. The first thing to do should be to check what the request data looks like.

Comment: You should view this it Help me Hope it will work for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/50749052/5968928