# CakePHP 3.4 - Array to string conversion warning calling setTemplates()

Tags: php, cakephp-3.4

I need to change the CSS class name on the wrapping div and therefore tried to use `setTemplates` example from [CakePHP book](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses).

I have just copied and pasted the following lines from the example:

`$myTemplates = [
    'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-control">{{content}}</div>',
];
$this->Form->setTemplates($myTemplates);`

After running the code I keep getting the `Array to string conversion` warning. The code is still working, but that warning is annoying as it is breaking the layout with debug turned on. I don't want to turn the debug off because of that silly warning. Any hint on how to get rid of it?

**EDIT**

As per suggestion here is the stacktrace:

```
include - APP/Template\Layout\default.ctp, line 49
Cake\View\View::_evaluate() - CORE\src\View\View.php, line 1010
Cake\View\View::_render() - CORE\src\View\View.php, line 971
Cake\View\View::renderLayout() - CORE\src\View\View.php, line 642
Cake\View\View::render() - CORE\src\View\View.php, line 600
Cake\Controller\Controller::render() - CORE\src\Controller\Controller.php, line 623
App\Controller\PagesController::display() - APP/Controller\PagesController.php, line 61
Cake\Controller\Controller::invokeAction() - CORE\src\Controller\Controller.php, line 440
Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\src\Http\ActionDispatcher.php, line 119
Cake\Http\ActionDispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\src\Http\ActionDispatcher.php, line 93
Cake\Http\BaseApplication::__invoke() - CORE\src\Http\BaseApplication.php, line 78
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 65
Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware::__invoke() - CORE\src\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php, line 59
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 65
Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware::__invoke() - CORE\src\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware.php, line 88
Cake\Http\Runner::__invoke() - CORE\src\Http\Runner.php, line 65
Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware::__invoke() - CORE\src\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php, line 93
```

Complete warning:

```
Notice (8): Array to string conversion [APP/Template\Layout\default.ctp, line 49]
```

Line 49:

```
'inputContainer' => '<div class="form-control">{{content}}</div>'
```

Comment: @Ayaou v3.4, read the title.

Comment: my bad :(, did you try `$this->Form->templates($myTemplates);` instead !

Comment: @Ayaou `templates` will be deprecated, but answering your question, yes I tried and the same warning is raised.

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP! Also show/describe the corresponding context, ie show/highlight the code that actually triggers the error, and please always mention your _exact_ (x.x.x) CakePHP version - thanks!

Comment: @ndm edited the question and added more details as per suggestion.

Comment: Are you you sure that you are looking at the correct file/stacktrace, respectively showing the correct code? I cannot see how defining an array element would cause that error.

Comment: That's a weird error, the `StringTemplateTrait::templates()` is not even mentionned !!

Comment: @ndm yes, I am sure. Whenever I remove these lines of code the warning is disappearing. Gonna create the helper file and see if that will do anything differently.

Comment: @Ayaou I believe that part is not even reached.

Comment: Using `$this->loadHelper('Form', [
    'templates' => 'app_form',
]);` helper worked. Thank you for your help guys!

Comment: Anyone please can give me an explanation, isn't `FormHelper` loaded by default in CakePHP ??

Comment: @Ayaou it is loaded by default. Line from the docs - `To change the templates when the helper is loaded you can set the templates option when including the helper in your controller`

Comment: No helpers are loaded by default, but rather the view supports autoloading via magic property access. Loading the helper explicitly shouldn't fix anything with regards to defining an array in a variable. I still believe that you are not showing the full/correct context, I can only imagine that you echo the variable somehow (for example by using the wrong PHP tags, ie `<?=`), but even then the error message should point to a different line, the line with the closing bracket

Comment: i think this will Help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50749052/5968928)